# Given a continuous matrix-valued mapping $t \in \mathbb{R} \to A(t)$ does the minimum singular value of $A(t)$ depend continuously on $t$?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

The question is as in the title.

Suppose that there is a continuous matrix-valued mapping $t \to A(t)$ on $\mathbb{R}$. Define
\begin{equation}
f(t):= \min \{  \text{singular values of } A(t)  \}
\end{equation}

Then, $f$ is a nonnegative function on $\mathbb{R}$. Also, I believe that it is continuous.

However, I cannot justify my intuition rigorously.. Could anyone please help me?

Comment: Follows from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem#Min-max_principle_for_singular_values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is continuous. More generally every singular value $\sigma_i$, when they are sorted in decreasing order, is continuous and even Lipschitz with respect to the operator norm as a function on matrices. This follows from the Weyl inequalities; see e.g. [this blog post](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2017/03/13/singular-value-decomposition/), which explains how to show that

$$|\sigma_i(A)- \sigma_i(B)| \le \| A - B \|.$$

The minimum singular value is $\sigma_n$ where $A$ and $B$ are $n \times n$ matrices, or more generally $\sigma_{\text{min}(m, n)}$ where $A$ and $B$ are $m \times n$ matrices.